# How To Align Button In Center Of Screen, After Creating FieldChange Listener

Tags: blackberry

I have written code to attach a fieldchange listener to a button.The issue is that i want this button centered.I know the code to center a button. The issue is to get code to both center the button and include a fieldchange listener to it. Here are some code snippets:

```
    FieldChangeListener listener = new FieldChangeListener() {
            public void fieldChanged(Field field, int context) {
                ButtonField register = (ButtonField) field;
                UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushScreen(new Register());

}
        }; 

       ButtonField register = new ButtonField("Register",ButtonField.CONSUME_CLICK);  
       register.setChangeListener(listener);
       add(register);
```

How can i center this button?

Comment: your question is some of confusion please specify clearly what do you want? do you want to center a button when click on the button or any other? if you have more doubts please visit this room http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4014/knowledge-sharing-center-for-blackberry-and-java

Comment: please move your update section from question into own answer and accept it - without this done, question is still active and people are still coming to help you (when you actually resolved it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I put two and two together and came up with this:

```
     FieldChangeListener listener = new FieldChangeListener() {
                  public void fieldChanged(Field field, int context) {
            ButtonField register = (ButtonField) field;
            UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushScreen(new Register());

    }
    };
          ButtonField menu = new ButtonField("Menu", Field.FIELD_HCENTER); 
      add(menu);
     add(new LabelField("New User?",Field.FIELD_HCENTER));
    ButtonField register = new ButtonField("Register",ButtonField.CONSUME_CLICK|Field.FIELD_HCENTER);  
  register.setChangeListener(listener);
  add(register);
```

This piece of code:

```
 ButtonField.CONSUME_CLICK|Field.FIELD_HCENTER
```

Is what does the trick